# If there is any possibility where we could create an jwt authentication token with certain length

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, token, jhipster

Currently I am working on framework Jhipster. I need to webhook my API's with ZOHO CRM. webhook needs authentication token.
The space provided by zoho is not more than 100 characters but jhipster generates Bearer of almost 200 characters.
I don't have zoho crm developer access.
Any solution?

Comment: the token length will be proportional to the number of claims in the token.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the zoho crm documentation](https://help.zoho.com/portal/kb/articles/jwt-for-authenticating-users-in-the-asap-add-ons#What_is_JWT)  the currently used jwt hashing algorithm should be `SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;` however in Jhipster they are using `SignatureAlgorithm.HS512` that you will find in **security/jwt/TokenProvider.java:72** I don't know if really this is the issue but maybe this will change the token to be acceptable by zoho if you update your jhipster to use the same `HS256`

As you can see in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) using `HS256` generates a shorter bearer token than using `HS512`

Comment: as per my information what i have searched zoho crm used OAuth for web hook its string is shorter than jwt.

Comment: as I believe, oauth is using towken generation mechanism you should be able to change the selected algorithm somehow in the token provider or interceptor, email me on talcorpdz@gmail.com for a pv discussion on this